# What makes a good quality pasta brand?

Tags: pasta, ingredient-selection

When I browse the pasta aisle I see a number of different brands (De Cecco, Rummo, etc.).  Are there any notable differences between these brands?

If I have a choice between different brands of the same pasta (spaghetti, penne, etc.), how should I determine which brand is appropriate for me?

Comment: In what region are you looking?

Comment: Spain. Most of the local shops and marjets just have Barilla or local brands, so I'm happy to buy online.

Comment: I think your question needs some more detail to really be on topic. Buying recommendations are generally off topic here. The question really is what makes a good pasta brand and how do you judge it. Can you please edit to include some of those criteria / questions? Otherwise it's likely to get closed.

Comment: Round in the US, Barilla is one of the better brands we can get.

Comment: @user65616 the question is almost unambigously about dried pasta, which usually has no eggs (apart from either a few specialty shapes or non-italian, eg german or chinese, styles).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biggest indicator I've found of quality dried pasta is how rough it feels when you rub it between your fingers.  Compare Barilla and De Cecco spaghetti to see what I mean.  The best brands use copper dies when extruding their pasta and this lends a rougher texture that will hold sauce better than plastic or teflon extruded pastas.

Comment: they are more often bronze dies than copper, but your point is still valid